# Label scatterplot points with derived axis in base R

Tags: r, label, scatter-plot

This is how my data looks like:

`> dput(head(GDP_NUTS2,5))`

```
structure(list(Regiao = c("N", "Ag", "C", "AML", "Al"), t2000 = c(10054.60679, 
13045.59069, 10621.51789, 18104.36306, 11585.29235), t2001 = c(10652.46712, 
13920.41552, 11101.08412, 18865.55149, 12014.61685), t2002 = c(11001.34917, 
14612.37052, 11507.36163, 19812.29293, 12411.44835), t2003 = c(11031.7278, 
15137.89461, 11884.96687, 20165.68892, 12889.20298), t2004 = c(11354.02317, 
15479.68985, 12364.05053, 21068.05117, 13448.52482), t2005 = c(11875.44359, 
16237.49791, 12754.40299, 21829.31373, 13867.5055), t2006 = c(12439.6426, 
17046.29326, 13378.47797, 22714.25829, 14767.48968), t2007 = c(13229.02402, 
17981.40383, 14044.39707, 23847.44923, 15362.11238), t2008 = c(13579.51144, 
18226.74178, 14091.85326, 24347.83971, 15335.54822), t2009 = c(13243.19054, 
17038.45595, 13974.46502, 23794.44899, 14836.93236), t2010 = c(13677.38358, 
16976.83391, 14284.14565, 24119.66719, 15489.72008), t2011 = c(13491.68626, 
16347.69468, 14011.54637, 23503.1765, 15200.84829), t2012 = c(13111.6173, 
16059.51047, 13623.68635, 22118.01701, 14510.73391), t2013 = c(13473.68717, 
16301.87448, 13919.18355, 22337.24739, 14628.8829), t2014 = c(13935.07757, 
16974.57715, 14220.1043, 22491.62875, 15021.05459), t2015 = c(14570.33755, 
17851.78088, 14983.95312, 23101.89351, 16297.81693), t2016 = c(15283.33044, 
19251.57661, 15620.77307, 23800.20038, 16737.39734), t2017 = c(16083.53849, 
20893.19975, 16410.11278, 24938.22636, 17888.34779), t2018 = c(17031.94867, 
22131.96942, 17242.70015, 25974.24055, 18396.58684), t2019 = c(17712.44223, 
23145.30242, 18045.54697, 26970.71178, 19006.1632)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In order to do the beta convergence plot I've used this pre-made code:

```
rca(GDP_NUTS2$t2000, 2000, GDP_NUTS2[3:21], 2019,  
    conditions=NULL, beta.plot=TRUE, beta.plotLine=TRUE, 
    beta.plotX="Ln (initial GDP p.c.)", beta.plotY="Ln (av. growth GDP p.c.)",
    beta.plotTitle="Beta convergence of Portuguese regions 2000-2019")
```

Since the axis are derived from the wrapper function `rca` and not directly from the dataset I don't know how to label the scatter plot points with the row names. All the examples that I saw were with a code plot structure completely different.

Any help will be much appreciatted.

Comment: The function `rca` comes from the package `{REAT}`.

Comment: yes, that's true, forgot to mention

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"label the scatter plots with the column names"_? I get just one plot with your code.

Comment: I'll edit my question to be more clear. What I mean was to label the points of the scatter plot with the row names and not the column name. My mistake, I'm sorry.

Comment: I think that you can't add point labels inside `rca`, the function does not appear to allow for that. Perhaps you could assign the `rca` results to an object, and then use `text` to add labels on the existing plot? I tried but got an error when executing your `rca` code above, saying : `Error in is.finite(y) : default method not implemented for type 'list' In addition: Warning message: Only last time period is regarded.`

Comment: I don't know exactly why that's happening. first, get "REAT", then reduce `GDP_NUTS2[3:21]` intervals. hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide enough data to run your code so I'll use a modified data set from the Examples on the manual page for `rca`.

```
library(REAT)
data (G.counties.gdp)   # GDP for German counties
Example <- G.counties.gdp[1:50, ]     # Just use the first 50 rows
out <- rca (Example$gdppc2010, 2010, Example$gdppc2011, 2011, 
       conditions = NULL, beta.plot = TRUE)
x <- out$betaconv$regdata$ln_initial
y <- out$betaconv$regdata$ln_growth
text(x, y, 1:50, pos=3, cex=.8)
```

The data for the axes is stored in the object that is returned when you run the function (if you assign it). Here's the plot:
[image: Plot]